# mkfifo - create a file that never experiences EOF etc

Tags: bash, shell, exec, cat, tail

I have this script:

```
mkfifo foo
exec 3<>foo
cat <&3 | while read line; do echo " [prepend] $line"; done &

echo "foo" >&3
echo "bar" >&3
echo "baz" >&3
```

I am just trying to prepend a string to each line of every command's stdout/stderr.

The problem is that the named pipe will experience EOF so the cat command will exit quickly.

Is there some file I can use instead of a named pipe that will never experience EOF? Such that a cat command used against it would basically never exit?

I could use `tail -f` instead of `cat` but I find `tail -f` to be wonky sometimes.

Comment: Just tried and found `cat` did not exit. Instead it continued running in background after the script completed. What's your purpose?

Comment: Yeah purpose is to prepend all stdout/stderr from the script with [xyz]...however, I found a better solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442461/using-process-substitution-only-send-stderr-to-process

Comment: I added an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238682/5047085

Answer (score 0):

To do what I want to do, this is probably a simpler technique:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442461/using-process-substitution-only-send-stderr-to-process

```
exec 2> >( while read line; do echo " stderr: $line"; done )
exec > >( while read line; do echo " stdout: $line"; done )

echo "rolo"
echo "cholo" >&2
```

the `exec` calls will set things up so stdout and stderr for the script get set to the processes in the process substitutions.